# Querying SQL Date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a query where the date shows up in a column which also has some text.

```
SELECT C.Caption, A.ErrorMessage
FROM [APM_CurrentStatistics] A, APM_Application B, NodesData C
join NodesData D on D.NodeID = C.NodeID
WHERE A.ApplicationID = B.ID
AND A.NodeID = C.NodeID
AND B.Name IN ('Database Backup')
AND A.ComponentName ='Incremental Backup'
AND A.ErrorMessage like '%Incremental%'
```

Output

```
May 20 03:40:29 server root: [ID 702911 local0.notice] Incremental Backup ended successfully;
May 21 02:00:07 server root: [ID 702911 local0.notice] Incremental Backup Started;
May 21 03:15:23 server root: [ID 702911 local0.notice] Incremental Backup ended successfully;
```

My requirement is to only output the data for today, in this case (May 21). Is there a date variable I can use when I do the `A.ErrorMessage like '%Today's DAY%Incremental%'`. Is there any other option available to display date only for today?

Comment: If you are learning SQL, learn proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.  NEVER use commas in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. I'm looking forward to when the table has more than one year's data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What database are you using? Something like this would work with SQL Server (updated since I didn't realize the data was in one field and not in separate rows)

```
SELECT C.Caption, [value], A.ErrorMessage
FROM [APM_CurrentStatistics] A
INNER JOIN APM_Application B ON A.ApplicationID=B.ID
INNER JOIN NodesData C ON A.NodeID=C.NodeID 
INNER JOIN NodesData D ON D.NodeID = C.NodeID
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(replace(c.caption, '<br/>', '|'), '|') 
WHERE 
B.Name IN ('Database Backup') AND
A.ComponentName ='Incremental Backup' AND
A.ErrorMessage like '%Incremental%' AND
[value] like format(getdate(), 'MMMM dd') + '%'
```

Comment: Yes that is correct. It is SQL Server. The data shows as below in SQL. I tried the like statement you provided and that did not rturn any data.                                         <br/>May 20 03:40:29 server root: [ID 702911 local0.notice] Incremental Backup ended successfully;<br/>May 21 02:00:07 server root: [ID 702911 local0.notice] Incremental Backup Started;<br/>May 21 03:15:23 server root: [ID 702911 local0.notice] Incremental Backup ended successfully;

Comment: I think the issue is that this data is in a single field/row. There are three entries in that one single field and there is no way to separate it out. The only separation is <br/>date; Will it be possible to still parse it?

Comment: I updated the query. I didn't realize it was all in one field. Not sure if it's the most efficient, but it seems to work. You'll need to use something different than a pipe if that is part of your normal data. Or you might be able to handle it as XML, but I figured this was an easier approach for now.